# Swift Bridging-Header Objective-C presentViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, bridging-header

I'm trying to use a view controller that is only available in Objective-C. I have set up my Bridging-Header, but when I run my method it doesn't include a `presentViewController` and gives the error `No visible @interface for 'AlertSelector' declares the selector 'presentViewController...'`

.m

```
#import "AlertSelector.h"

@implementation AlertSelector : NSObject

- (void) someMethod {
    NSLog(@"SomeMethod Ran");
    UIAlertController * view=   [UIAlertController
                             alertControllerWithTitle:@"My Title"
                             message:@"Select you Choice"
                             preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];

    UIAlertAction* ok = [UIAlertAction
                     actionWithTitle:@"OK"
                     style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                     handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                     {
                         //Do some thing here
                         [view dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

                     }];
    UIAlertAction* cancel = [UIAlertAction
                         actionWithTitle:@"Cancel"
                         style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                         handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                         {
                             [view dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

                         }];

[view addAction:ok];
[view addAction:cancel];
[self presentViewController:view animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

.h

```
@interface AlertSelector : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) id someProperty;

- (void) someMethod;

@end
```

From Swift

```
var instanceOfCustomObject: AlertSelector = AlertSelector()
    instanceOfCustomObject.someProperty = "Hello World"
    print(instanceOfCustomObject.someProperty)
    instanceOfCustomObject.someMethod()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `AlertSelector` class is not a subclass of `UIViewController`. This is why you cannot call `[self presentViewController:view animated:YES completion:nil];` from an instance of `AlertSelector`.

Add a view controller parameter to your `someMethod` method and present from that instead of self.

Answer (score 0):

presentViewController is a method of UIViewController. Your AlertSelector class is not a UIViewController.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with bridging header. It's the `UIViewController` which implements `presentViewController:` not `NSObject`, therefore the compiler complains, because the method `presentViewController:` is not present on `NSObject`'s interface.

#### Possible Solution

Either implement the `presentViewController:` yourself (which is a difficult task) or let the `AlertSelector` extend from `UIViewController`

.h

`@interface AlertSelector : UIViewController`